# Response must be a string on socialite facebook

Tags: laravel

> UnexpectedValueException
>   The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

```php
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    /* echo "redirect checking";*/
    return Socialite::driver('facebook');
}

public function handleProvidercallback()
{
    /* echo "callback coming";*/
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    dd($user);
    //return $user->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `redirect` function on the driver

```php
return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/socialite#routing)

Hope this helps